# Split string to a 2-dimensional array in Scala

Tags: arrays, string, scala

In Scala:
Is there a way to directly split a string that contains 72 numeric values separated by ; into a 2-dimensional array of 9 rows and 8 columns with those numeric values -in numeric data type-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val input = List.tabulate(72)(_.toString).mkString(";")
input.split(";").map(_.toInt).grouped(9).toArray
```

transforms

```
0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71
```

into

```
Array(
  Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
  Array(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), 
  Array(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26), 
  Array(27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35), 
  Array(36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44), 
  Array(45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53), 
  Array(54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62), 
  Array(63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71)
)
```

If you want to swap the dimensions of rows/columns, replace `9` by `8`.

Comment: They can do a `transpose` to get column-major from row-major and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

using Range and grouped functions

```
scala> val a = (0 to 71).map(_.toString).toArray.mkString(";")
a: String = 0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71

scala> a.split(";").map(_.toInt).sliding(9,9).toArray
res269: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Array(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), Array(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26), Array(27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35), Array(36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44), Array(45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53), Array(54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62), Array(63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71))

scala>
```

Comment: Re-read the question. You missed the part about "split a string".